# Different behaviour of Gradles's zipTree on Unix and Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, gradle, relative-path, absolute-path

I have ***SourceTask*** and I specify it's source property:

*On Windows*

```
source = zipTree("/src/main/resources/problems/problems.zip")
```

*On Linux*

```
source = zipTree(project.file(project.rootDir).path+"/src/main/resources/problems/problems.zip")
```

This code works but if On Linux I write the same as Windows Gradle says that the file do not exist.

Why on Windows Gradle takes the path as relative, but on Linux Gradle takes it as absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because on Linux a leading slash means an absolute path. Did you try without the leading slash? E.g.:

```
source = zipTree("src/main/resources/problems/problems.zip")
```

Comment: Now I notice that with / on Windows takes the root project dir, but without slash takes the buildSrc dir.(I call the method from project in the buildSrc). So only zipTree(project.file(project.rootDir).path+"/src/main/resources/problems/problems.zip") works in  both ways.